# Probability of two person competing the race not winning the race.

Tags: probability

If  probability of a in winning the race is 1/5 and that of b is 1/2. What is the probability that neither of them win the race.

I get the solution when I do 1-p(either of them winning)

But when I try x = p(a not winning)*p(b not winning) I get a different answer.

Aren't 'a not winning' and 'b not winning' independent events? Meaning a not winning the race looks to be totally independent of b weather b wins the race or not.

So what is wrong with the above reasoning.

Comment: Regarding the intuition: consider a simpler example where $a$ and $b$ are the only two people in the race. Surely if we know that $a$ did not win, then that improves $b$'s chances of winning (to 100% in this case!)

Comment: @Bungo If there were only two person is it possible for the probabilities to not add up to 1?

Comment: That's why I called it a simpler example, not the *same* example.

Comment: P(A not winning | B not winning) = P(A not winning and B not winning) / P(B not winning) = (1 - 1/5 - 1/2) / (1/2) = 3/5, which is lower than P(A not winning) = 4/5. So, knowing that B did not win decreases the likelihood that A did not win, or equivalently, increases the likelihood that A won. It's the same principle as in my previous example, just not quite as extreme.

Comment: @Bungo Thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

Probability of $B$ wins given that $A$ wins would be $0$. (assuming one champion)

Probability of $B$ wins is non-zero. Hence the event of $A$ winning and the event that $B$ winning are not independent.

Answer (score 0):

It should be $1 - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{5} = \frac{3}{10}$. If $b$ wins then it's certain that $a$ has lost.